# Решить логическое выражение в Coq

Tags: haskell, emacs, булева-алгебра, ocaml

Язык:`Coq`

Есть цель:

```
(some_function x || true)%bool = true
```

С помощью какой тактики можно ее решить, не рассматривая первую часть?

Answer (score -1):

```
Require Import Coq.ssr.ssrbool.

rewrite orbT. reflexivity.
```